# Pandas df: fill values in new column with specific values from another column (condition with multiple columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'col2': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'col3': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})

  col1 col2  col3
0    a    b   1.0
1    b    c   2.0
2    c    d   3.0
3    d    e   4.0
```

My goal is to create an additional col4 that contains specific values from col3 with a conditon: for each row x, look at the value in col1 and if there is another row y anywhere in the df where this value is present in col2, take the col3 value form this row y and put it as col4 into the original row x. Otherwise, leave col4 empty for this row, e.g. NaN.

So the expected output for col4 is: NaN, 1, 2, 3. For the first row there is no value as there is no row in the dataframe that has 'a' is col2. **Unlike in this example, the rows can be completely unsorted in the df!**

```
Expected output:

  col1 col2  col3  col4
0    a    b   1.0   NaN
1    b    c   2.0   1.0
2    c    d   3.0   2.0
3    d    e   4.0   3.0
```

I have tried using .mask but no luck so far. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Will you please provide a sample expected output dataframe to help me visulize the requirements?

Comment: I edited it into the question.

Comment: I noticed that NaN is not possible in columns with dtype int, so I changed col3 to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join the dataframe to itself using col1 on the left side & col2 on the right side.

rename `col3` from the right side of the join to `col4` and drop the rest of the right side columns
example:

```py
df = df.merge(df, left_on='col1', right_on='col2', how='left', suffixes=('', '_'))
df = df.rename(columns={'col3_': 'col4'})
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']]
```

df looks like:

```
  col1 col2  col3  col4
0    a    b     1   NaN
1    b    c     2   1.0
2    c    d     3   2.0
3    d    e     4   3.0
```